# error using google-api-python

Tags: python, google-api

I have a piece of code like this:

```
import urllib2,urllib 
import json

GOOGLE_API_KEY = "api-key"

target = "packtpub.com"

token = ""

loops = 0

while loops < 10:

    api_response = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people?query="+target+"&key="+GOOGLE_API_KEY+"&maxResults=50& pageToken="+token).read()

    json_response = json.loads(api_response)
    token = json_response['nextPageToken']

    if len(json_response['items']) == 0:
        break

for result in json_response['items']:
    name = result['displayName']
    print name
    image = result['image']['url'].split('?')[0]
```

and i got error:

```
 Bad Request

 File "googleadditional.py", line 10, in <module>
    api_response = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people?query="+target+"&key="+GOOGLE_API_KEY+"&maxResults=50& pageToken="+token).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400:
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: You have a space in your URL (`& pageToken`), that might cause the problem

Comment: Also, have you entered your APi key in place of `"api-key"`?

Comment: thanks i got it working ....error because of space..